# Is $S^0$ a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, definition

Consider a singleton space $\{x\}$, it is a manifold and it is locally euclidean as there is a homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^0$. However, consider $S^0=\{-1,1\}$ with the discrete topology, there does not exist any homeomorphism to any open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k \ge 0$, so it cannot be locally euclidean and cannot be therefore a manifold.

So is $S^0$ the most trivial example of a topological space that is not a manifold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Locally Euclidean' means each point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$. Each point in $S^0$ *does* have this property for $k = 0$.

More generally, any countable discrete space is a $0$-manifold.

Comment: +1, though just a minor comment: if one requires manifolds to be second-countable, then uncountable discrete spaces are not $0$-manifolds.

Comment: @ZevChonoles That's a fair point. Edited my answer. Thanks for your comment!